# What is overriding the CSS rule?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Here is another unexpected outcome of a CSS rule. (Yesterday I posted this that was not understood here: [How to I avoid that the CSS rule * {} trump .a .b {}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350002/how-to-i-avoid-that-the-css-rule-trump-a-b))

For historical reasons I have these CSS rules:

```css
:root {
    --baseFontSize: 16px;
}
html {
    font-size: var(--baseFontSize);
}
```

The last rule shows up in Chrome on a P element. The computed value of `--baseFontSize` on that element is " 16px". The "Computed Style" shows that the last rule used is the rule above.

But. The value is "20.8px".

What is going on?

Comment: we don't see any P element and no "20.8px"

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, you do not see them. This is a bit more technical question.

Comment: and everyone is talking about specifity in your other question where it's not involved there. Only one selector is selecting your i element which is `*` so it applies logically.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I know, but it is very easy to miss that. (And solving the problem is not very hard either, but no one came up with an answer.)

Comment: *No, you do not see them.* If we cannot see/reproduce the result we cannot help you. You are the only one seeing the 20.8px value.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Perhaps. But it depends on what kind of knowledge you have.

Comment: What @TemaniAfif means is that you need to provide us with a [mcve]. Otherwise we can't do anything here.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, I know, but it is not that kind of problem. (It is probably a bug.)

Comment: @Leo I disagree. A bug that would produce such a glaring error would be caught instantly and would not appear in release. Or, are you using Chrome Canary?

Comment: @MrLister Then I guess you have not filed very many bug reports.

Comment: @MrLister No, I do not use Canary. (Then I would not have been asking here.)

Answer (score 1):

If we create a html document with your variables it can be seen that the value is indeed 16px as expected. So there are no 20.8px anywhere.

Maybe you zoomed in on browser? Set a different font-size on your OS?

```css
:root {
    --baseFontSize: 16px;
}
html {
    font-size: var(--baseFontSize);
}
```

```html
<p> Here be text </p>
```

Comment: That won't produce the result in the OP's question. Even zoomed in, the computed style of the p will still be 16px.

Comment: I think zooming in is a good guess. I even had to check earlier today. Zoom is 100%. But on an older mobile I used to have zoom on maybe 130% (which would give 20.8...) However I do not see this "zoom" on all elements.